# Ros2 not finding executables running in Docker

Tags: docker, ros2

I'm trying to run a python script with ros2 in my docker container, and everything up to running the Script works, I can even run Gazebo via a launch file, and it works.

The Error ROS gives me is the following:

```
root@86d8bf3a6eb9:/# ros2 run field_robot robot_spawner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.9.11', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')()
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 67, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2run/command/run.py", line 70, in main
    return run_executable(path=path, argv=args.argv, prefix=prefix)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2run/api/__init__.py", line 61, in run_executable
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/field_robot/dev_ws/install/field_robot/lib/field_robot/robot_spawner.py'
```

And yes, I checked, the File actually exists:

```
root@86d8bf3a6eb9:/# ls -l /field_robot/dev_ws/install/field_robot/lib/field_robot/robot_spawner.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1964 Apr 12 14:37 /field_robot/dev_ws/install/field_robot/lib/field_robot/robot_spawner.py
```

Also, I'm running the Host system on Windows, so it could be that something with windows is fucked up, so if you have an Idea what could be the Problem there, that also might be it

Comment: is that supposed to be a python node or a launch file?

Comment: It's a python node

Comment: Does your script have a correct `#!` at the start?

Comment: I'm not 100% shure, It starts with `#!/usr/bin/python3`, i think that should be the right one

Comment: Have you written/touched the file on a Windows machine? Or Just within the docker container?

Comment: I'm editing the src files from Windows, but didn't touche the compiled Version in any way

EDIT: Except of course when I checked if they where there and read the Content, which was done both from inside the container and from the Host Windows machine, but I never wrote anything to the build output, e.g. the `/install` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it appears you're running into this issue because of the file type. If they're being edited in Windows first it is likely they are DOS files and not UNIX files. I know this causes issues with ROS1 so I assume it's the case in ROS2 as well. To fix this, you have a couple of options.

Usually the easiest would be to use `dos2unix`. This isn't installed by default but you can get it via `apt install dos2unix` assuming your image is Ubuntu. The files can be converted by running `dos2unix <filename>` inside your container.

Comment: It worked, I was stuck at this since Saturday xD

Big think you :D